# CListBox Set/Get wrong data pointer

Tags: windows, visual-studio, mfc

I use SetItemDataPtr to set listbox items pointers to my data, but i cannot get correct pointer when i call GetItemDataPtr?

For ex:

// Set data pointer when init listbox
m_lstBox.SetItemDataPtr(0, pointer); //pointer = 0x0123CDEF
.....

// In DrawItem()
pointer = GetItemDataPtr(lpDrawItemStruct->itemID); //lpDrawItemStruct->itemID = 0

// **pointer != 0x0123CDEF**

Why is that?

LR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inserted, removed, sorted or reordered the items.

Martyn

Comment: i made simple test without any of those operation, and I figured out what happen. After calling SetItemDataPtr, I called SetItemData to set another value for item. When i call GetItemDataPtr i get the value which i passed in SetItemData. i'm now confusing the uses of those two function.

Comment: You can only have one or the other. They use the same storage. The Data vs DataPtr versions simply provide the right semantics for 64 bit vs 32 bit OSes.